# How can I find the coordinates of a pixel in Photoshop CS4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, cs4

Lets say i create a new document of `800px x 800px` and I take the cursor on a particular point in the document. How would I know which pixel this cursor is at this moment?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **Info panel** will tell you what position your mouse is at.

To display your info panel go to `Window > Info`, or hit <kbd>F8</kbd> on your keyboard.

[image]

Also note that it may default to a unit of measurement  other than pixels such as centimeters or inches. If this is the case, click on the "+." next to X and Y as highlighted in the picture above, and select Pixels from the drop-down menu.